# how to control if libraries are installed on the system in python

Tags: python, function, module

is there a way to create a function that check on the system if the python modules that are needed by the main program are installed and eventually install them automatically?
I searched a lot for something like this but i didn't found anything useful.
Thanks and sorry for the bad english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you are likely looking for is pip, it's not run as a part of a script but rather is used to install a script.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/

In addition if you wish to develop a script to install your script you can find documentation

http://marthall.github.io/blog/how-to-package-a-python-app/